# How to inject many dependencies into a controller using IoC in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

I am trying to refactor my controller and put everything into services. At the moment I have 6 methods in the controller, so I need to add 6 services to use them. As I understand it, doing something like this for 6 services is not entirely normal. So is there any other,better way to inject dependencies in my controller?

```
public function __construct(CreateRecoveryEmailService $service,ChangePasswordService $changePasswordService)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
        $this->changePasswordService = $changePasswordService;
    }
```

Comment: You can use binding with tagging, you can find informations & documentation here : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container

Comment: you could use Method Injection to inject the dependencies at the method level if you prefer https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers